# c++ aggregate has incomplete type and cannot be defined with template class

Tags: c++, templates, queue

This is the first time that I have a Problem that I cant solve with simple googleing.
I have a Problem with a Homework assignement in c++. As Startup, we are not allowed to change the main.cpp.
The Task is, to write a double linked list and to use Template Classes.

I get the errors

```
aggregate Queue<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > q1' has incomplete type and cannot be defined Queue<string> q1;
```

and

```
variable 'Queue<double> q3' has initializer but incomplete type
Queue<double> q3(q2);
```

If I google those Errors, the answere is, that I probably have not properly declared my class in the header file or a similar declaration or definition mistake. But I cant find the mistake I made.

I have tryed different apporaches with the Constructor (with and without initializer list). I experimented with the spezialisations. If I put the spezialisation of the friend operator<< in the header file (which I were thought to always do) I get this error:

```
expected initializer before '<' token
 std::ostream& operator<< <std::string>
```

I hope you can help me.

Here is the main.cpp which should not be changed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

#include "Queue.hpp"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;

    Queue<string> q1;
    cout << "Queue q1 ist leer: " << q1.empty() << endl << endl;
    q1.push("Bergische");
    q1.push("Universitaet");
    q1.push("Wuppertal");
    cout << "Queue q1:" << endl << q1 << endl;
    cout << "Pop erstes Element: " << q1.pop() << endl << endl;
    cout << "Queue q1:" << endl << q1 << endl;

    Queue<double> q2;
    q2.push(3.1415);
    q2.push(2.7182);
    cout << "Queue q2:" << endl << q2 << endl;
    cout << "Groesse von q2: " << q2.size() << endl << endl;
    Queue<double> q3(q2);
    cout << "Queue q3 aus q2 mit Copy-Konstruktor: " << q3 << endl;

    Queue<int> q4;
    for(int i=0; i<100000000; ++i)
        q4.push(i);
    cout << "Groesse von q4: " << q4.size() << endl;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(8);
    cout << "Beginne Zeitmessung Copy-Konstruktor... " << flush;
    clock_t start = clock();
    Queue<int> q4copy(q4);
    clock_t end = clock();
    cout << (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " Sekunden" << endl;

    cout << "Groesse von q4:     " << q4.size() << endl;
    cout << "Groesse von q4copy: " << q4copy.size() << endl;

    cout << "Beginne Zeitmessung Move-Konstruktor... " << flush;
    start = clock();
    Queue<int> q4move(move(q4));
    end = clock();
    cout << (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " Sekunden" << endl;

    cout << "Groesse von q4:     " << q4.size() << endl;
    cout << "Groesse von q4move: " << q4move.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the Queue.hpp:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_HPP_
#define QUEUE_HPP_


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class Queue;

template<typename T>
class Queue_el{
private:
    Queue_el* pHeadEl;
    Queue_el* pTailEl;
    T data;
public:
    Queue_el(Queue_el* a = nullptr, Queue_el* b = nullptr);
    Queue_el(const Queue_el &q);
    ~Queue_el();

    Queue_el& operator=(Queue_el q);

    friend class Queue<T>;
    template<typename U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Queue_el<U> &q);
};

template<typename T>
class Queue{
private:
    Queue_el<T>* pHead;
    Queue_el<T>* pTail;
public:
    Queue(Queue_el<T>* a = nullptr, Queue_el<T>* b = nullptr);
    Queue(const Queue &q);
    ~Queue();
    Queue(Queue&& q);

    Queue& operator=(const Queue&q);
    Queue& operator=(Queue&& q);

    void push(T data) const;
    T pop() const;
    bool empty() const;
    int size() const;

    friend class Queue_el<T>;
    template <typename U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Queue<U> &q);


};



template<> class Queue_el<std::string>;
template<> class Queue_el<double>;
template<> class Queue_el<int>;

template<> class Queue<std::string>;
template<> class Queue<double>;
template<> class Queue<int>;


#endif /* QUEUE_HPP_ */
```

and the Queue.cpp:

```
#include "Queue.hpp"


template<typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue(Queue_el<T>* a, Queue_el<T>* b)
        :pHead(a), pTail(b)
{

};

template<typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue(const Queue<T> &q) {
    Queue_el<T> *buffer = nullptr;
    Queue_el<T> *bufferq = q.pHead;

    buffer = new Queue_el<T>;
    pHead = buffer;
    buffer = buffer->pTailEl;
    bufferq = bufferq->pTailEl;

    while (bufferq->pTailEl != nullptr){
        buffer = new Queue_el<T>;
        *buffer = *bufferq;
        buffer = buffer->pTailEl;
        bufferq = bufferq->pTailEl;

    }
    pTail = buffer;
}

template<typename T>
Queue<T>::~Queue() {
    if (pHead != nullptr) {
        Queue_el<T> *buffer1 = pHead;
        Queue_el<T> *buffer2 = pHead;
        while (buffer1->pTailEl != nullptr) {
            buffer1 = buffer1->pTailEl;
            delete buffer2;
            buffer2 = buffer1;
        }
        delete buffer1;
    }
}

template<typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue(Queue<T> &&q){ //move Konstruktor
    pHead = q.pHead;
    pTail = q.pTail;
    q.pHead = nullptr;
    q.pTail = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
Queue<T>& Queue<T>::operator=(const Queue<T> &q) {
    if (this != &q) {
        if (pHead != nullptr) {     
            Queue_el<T> *buffer1 = pHead;
            Queue_el<T> *buffer2 = pHead;
            while (buffer1->pTailEl != nullptr) {
                buffer1 = buffer1->pTailEl;
                delete buffer2;
                buffer2 = buffer1;
            }
            delete buffer1;
            pHead = nullptr;
            pTail = nullptr;
        }

        if (q.pHead != nullptr) {   

            Queue_el<T> *buffer = pHead;
            Queue_el<T> *bufferq = q.pHead;

            do {
                buffer = new Queue_el<T>;
                *buffer = *bufferq;
                buffer = buffer->pTailEl;
                bufferq = bufferq->pTailEl;

            } while (bufferq->pTailEl != nullptr);
            pTail = buffer;

        }

    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
Queue<T>& Queue<T>::operator=(Queue<T> &&q) { 
    if(this != &q){
    pHead = q.pHead;
    pTail = q.pTail;
    q.pHead = nullptr;
    q.pTail = nullptr;

    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::push(T data) const {
    if (pTail != nullptr) {
        pTail->pTailEl = new Queue_el<T>;
        pTail->pTailEl->pHeadEl = pTail;
        pTail = pTail->pTailEl;
        *pTail = data;
    } else {                        
        pTail = new Queue_el<T>(data);
        pHead = pTail;
    }
    return;
}

template<typename T>
T Queue<T>::pop() const {
    if (pHead != nullptr) {
        if (pHead->pTailEl != nullptr) {
            Queue_el<T> *buffer = pHead;
            pHead = pHead->pTailEl;
            pHead->pHeadEl = nullptr;
            std::cout <<"Pop here: ";
            return buffer;
        } else {
            Queue_el<T> *buffer = pHead;
            delete pHead;
            pHead = nullptr;
            pTail = nullptr;
            return *buffer;
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
bool Queue<T>::empty() const {
    if (pHead == nullptr) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

template<typename T>
int Queue<T>::size() const {
    int i = 0;
    if (pHead != nullptr) {
        Queue_el<T> *buffer = pHead;
        i++;
        while (buffer->pTailEl != nullptr) {
            buffer = buffer->pTailEl;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

template<typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Queue<U> &q){
    if(q.pHead != nullptr){
        Queue_el<U>* buffer = q.pHead;
        os << buffer << std::endl;          
        while(buffer->pTailEl != nullptr){  
            buffer = buffer->pTailEl;
            os << buffer << std::endl;
            };
    }
    return os;
}

template<> std::ostream& operator<< <std::string>
            (std::ostream& os, const Queue<std::string> &q);
template<> std::ostream& operator<< <double>
            (std::ostream& os, const Queue<double> &q);
template<> std::ostream& operator<< <int>
            (std::ostream& os, const Queue<int> &q);




template<typename T>
Queue_el<T>::Queue_el(Queue_el<T>* a, Queue_el<T>* b)
        :pHeadEl(a), pTailEl(b)
{

}

template<typename T>
Queue_el<T>::Queue_el(const Queue_el<T> &q)
{
    data = q.data;
    pHeadEl = nullptr;
    pTailEl = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
Queue_el<T>::~Queue_el(){
    std::cout << "Element zerstört" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
Queue_el<T>& Queue_el<T>::operator=(Queue_el<T> q){
    data = q.data;
    return data;
}

template<typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Queue_el<U> &q){
    os << q.data;
    return os;
}

template<>
std::ostream& operator<< <std::string> (std::ostream& os, const Queue_el<std::string> &q);
template<>
std::ostream& operator<< <double>(std::ostream& os, const Queue_el<double> &q);
template<>
std::ostream& operator<< <int>(std::ostream& os, const Queue_el<int> &q);
```

Comment: `template<> class Queue<std::string>;`? is a declaration of **template (full) specialization**. Is it what you wanted? If you wanted to provide **explicit template instantiation**, the correct syntax is `template class Queue<std::string>;`. However, it must be placed where the template is fully defined, that is, at the end of `Queue.cpp` in your case.

Comment: That could be it. I have to do more debuging now to see if it worked. But now the errors atleast make sense again.

Comment: That **is** it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of `Queue.hpp`, you have:

```
template<> class Queue_el<std::string>;
template<> class Queue_el<double>;
template<> class Queue_el<int>;

template<> class Queue<std::string>;
template<> class Queue<double>;
template<> class Queue<int>;
```

All of these constructs **declare template specializations** of corresponding class templates `Queue_el` and `Queue`.

What you likely wanted is **explicit template instantiation**. The difference in the syntax is that the latter is missing `<>` after `template` keyword:

```
template class Queue_el<std::string>;
template class Queue_el<double>;
template class Queue_el<int>;

template class Queue<std::string>;
template class Queue<double>;
template class Queue<int>;
```

However, note that this can be done only at a place where the template is fully defined. Therefore, you need to put it **at the end of `Queue.cpp`**, instead of at the end of `Queue.hpp`:

Comment: This is insufficient/poor: the explicit template instantiation in the .cpp file will not prevent the compiler to create another one upon seeing the .hpp file. See my answer for how to do this properly.

Comment: @Walter It depends on what do you mean by _insufficient/poor_. It works and does not produce any compile-time errors ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ji4ew7SdVXMImBNw)). However, agree that it is better to provide `extern` declarations to reduce compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

As remarked in the comments

```
template<> class Queue<std::string>;
```

declares the full template specialization for `T=std::string`, but then does not provide the definition, hence `Queue<std::string>` is an incomplete type.

If you want to pre-compile the instantination `Queue<std::string>` then you should do the follow **two** things:

1. In file Queue.hpp at the end add the line

   ```
   extern template class Queue<std::string>;
   ```

   which tells the compiler that an instantiation exists elsewhere and prevents it from creating another one.
2. In file Queue.cpp at the end add the line

   ```
   template class Queue<std::string>;
   ```

   which creates the actual instantiation promised by the `extern` statement in the header file.

Moreover, it would make the design easier if the element type is a nested type within `Queue<T>`: then no separate explicit instantiation is needed.